# Dynamically change the backgorund image of app header (Polymer)

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

The app header styling looks like this

```
app-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 212px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3f51b5;
  --app-header-background-front-layer: {
    background-image: url(//app-layout-assets.appspot.com/assets/bg1.jpg);
    background-position: left center;
  };
}




<app-header condenses reveals effects="waterfall resize-title blend-background parallax-background">
  <app-toolbar>
  <paper-icon-button icon="menu"></paper-icon-button>
     <h4 condensed-title>What is material? &mdash; Environment</h4>
  <paper-icon-button icon="search"></paper-icon-button>
</app-toolbar>
<app-toolbar class="tall">
    <h1 main-title>What is material?</h1>
</app-toolbar>
```

How do I dynamically change the background image url and swap it with my own in javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

href$="{{imgURL}}"

Use a computed property or an observer to change the image.

Take Care